# Move rangehood fan inline

Tags: kitchens, exhaust

I have one of these [rangehoods](http://www.harveynorman.co.nz/whiteware/kitchen/rangehoods/robinhood-696mm-integrated-powerpack-rangehood.html), the fan is built in directly above the filters so its noisy as hell when you run it.

I don't really want to spend $1K+ on a new "silent" rangehood, I was wondering if anyone can see any issues with buying an inline fan and moving it up into the ceiling to sit halfway along the vent, hopefully reducing the noise in the kitchen considerably.

Note: It's only venting steam / smells, etc. Cooktop is electric.

Comment: What about *grease* that gets into the vent system?

Comment: Sounds like you want to install another fan in series with the existing fan and use that new one instead?  If so 1) the new fan will need to be strong, much stronger (=loud!) than the existing fan to pull sufficient air through the vent pipe and 2) the existing fan will further impede the performance of the new fan making issue 1) even worse.

Comment: Grease could be an issue, the inside of the fan thats there now looks pretty clean after 18 months use so hopefully its not a huge issue. Are there specific types of inline fans you'd need for a kitchen system or will any old bathroom rated fan with sufficient airflow do?

I was planning on removing the existing fan so that won't be in the way of any other fan I install. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Grease isn't any more of a concern than it is now if the existing traps remain in place. If it was, the original fan would also be in jeopardy.

Airflow isn't really a concern, either. The original fan can probably be easily removed (and the new one connected to its power supply). Even if it can't, it won't reduce flow much, especially if it spins passively.

There's no need for a super-turbo-jet-fan. Anything that claims to move as much air as the original is suitable, and the fact that it's remote should significantly reduce noise.

I'm with you on the noise thing. I don't understand why remote fans aren't the default. My new "low sones" bath fan buzzes like a chainsaw half the time.

Go for it.

Answer (score 2):

This is done all the time. Just make sure you get one that is approved for range hoods. They do make some considerations for the grease. For a typical home system grease is generally of little concern. Make sure to take the original fan out to reduce pressure. There will of course be some electrical work as well.